# Как поменять значение по умолчанию сетки в категориях?

Tags: opencart

При просмотре товаров категории активна кнопка 2 ,мне нужно что бы при загрузке активна была 4[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос касается реализации функционала кастомной темы, поэтому ответить наверняка вам смогут лишь разработчики темы либо те, кто имел дело именно с этой темой.

> **указывайте в заголовке вопроса версию opencart и название шаблона**

Общий рецепт таков:

- в файле представления (судя по фото - **`category.twig`**) ищите место, где выводятся эти фильтры и смотрите, какие переменные там фигурируют;
- в связанном контроллере (опять же, скорее всего - **`category.php`**) ищите место, где формируются эти переменные;
- Анализируете код, находите нужные переменные, меняете выводы так, как вам надо.